# How can I concat and still keep columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of files, that I want to put into a massive dataframe so I can run easy queries on it like figuring out the average/mean of a column etc. I have this bit of code:

```
def read_files():
    path = 'data'
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
    df_list = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in files]
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
    print(df.to_string())
    return df
```

but this gives all of my data in one column it seems. when I try to access certain columns using df['x'] I receive key errors. How can I keep my csv structure when concating? All files will have the same columns and if they don't have the same columns I don't want to read them if that matters.

Comment: Check reading in a single file, and see whether or not it comes back as 1 column or many. My bet is that your csv files have a missing first row or something, and its reading the whole things as 1 column for all of them. If that IS the case, try using `skiprows` argument of `pd.read_csv`

Comment: also, figure out exactly the format you want to import a single file to make sure it works with one file. don't write the function first, do it with 1 file, and then write the list comprehension, and then wrap a function around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

to

```
df = df_list[0]
for df_tmp in df_list[1:]:    
    df = df_tmp.combine_first(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I get a different error this time which is this: ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: Index(['fname', ' lname', ' age'], dtype='object')

Comment: My mistake. I thought verify_integrity would take care of it, but it just raises an error. Altered my answer to variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106361/concatenating-pandas-dataframes-with-overlapping-indexes-but-never-overlapping-v)